# Dynamically creating sums from lookups

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to do something similar to this post: [Google Sheets advanced lookup + sum](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67195/google-sheets-advanced-lookup-sum)

But I just can't figure out how to amend it for my purpose.

I'm basically building a diet plan, where I have recipes broken down into the constituent foods and their nutrient worth (Calories, Proteins, Carbs etc)

The hope is that I can build at the end a sheet which has daily plans where I can select (or otherwise not select) a series of foods from the lookup sheet and then be able to tally/sum the values being looked up.

So imagine as follows:

Sheet: Recipe

[image: Recipe Sheet]

has the data.

Sheet Plan has (or should) have the tallies/sum, where based on the choice of the meal/recipe from the lookup, I'm able to sum the correct corresponding values multiplied by the number of servings retrieved from column F on sheet Plan.  The categories are a vertical pivot of the categories in the recipe (Calorie, Fat, [Carb - Fibre], Proten)

[image: Plan sheet]

I've tried simplifying my life a bit by creating a lookup sheet at the moment, but I'm not sure how to go forward.

[image: Look sheet]

Suggestions?

MAJOR bonus points for explanations of commands and formulae as I am not a spreadsheet master in any way!

Intended final Plan sheet:

[image]

Comment: @pnuts I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @pnuts after some coffee, I understood what you meant and I added the intended look for the Plan sheet

Comment: :) nope because net carbs are what count and net carbs = carbs - fibre

Comment: Your maths are correct. The table was entered text to present what I'm trying to achieve, the values in there are completely bogus.

Comment: @pnuts any suggestions?